# Can't Access Task of microsoft project with c#

Tags: c#, ms-project

I want to loop all task of Microsoft project with c# bellow is my loop

```
foreach (MSProject.Project t in project.Tasks)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(t.ToString());
                foreach (MSProject.Project s in t.OutlineChildren)
                {
                    if (s.Summary)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }
```

But in run time it shows error System.InvalidCastException on MSProject.Project and when I use MSProject.Tasks for t variable But again shows me error. How can I solve this problem. 
Another Question here is how to access column number20 of ms project in this loop?

Comment: you have it backwards a task is a part of a project.  Not a project is part of a task....

Comment: o.k thank you , now how to access column number20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this instead :

```
foreach (MSProject.Task t in project.Tasks)
{
  MessageBox.Show(t.ToString());
}
```